# ReactNative - Error when using push in NavigatorIOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am building a small ReactNative+Redux app. I am currently using a `ListView` to display a list of job items. When I tap on an item in the list, I want to navigate to a detail view (`JobDetailComponent`) using `NavigatorIOS`.

I have the following setup at the moment:

#### index.ios.js

```
class HackerJobs extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
          ...
          <TabBarIOS.Item
            selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Jobs'}
            title='Jobs'
            onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({
                      selectedTab: 'Jobs',
                  })
            }}>
            <NavigatorIOS
              style={styles.navigatorWrapper}
              initialRoute={{
                component: JobsRootComponent,
                title: 'Jobs'
             }}
           />
          </TabBarIOS.Item>
          ...
    )
  }

}
```

#### JobsRootComponent.js

```
class JobsRootComponent extends Component {

  ...

  _pressRow(rowData, row) {
    console.log('JobsRootComponent - _pressRow ', row)
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: 'Details',
      component: JobDetailComponent,
      passProps: { test: 'XXX' }
    })
  }

  _renderRow(rowData, section, row) {
    const title = rowData.title
    const subtitle = 'by ' + rowData.by
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._pressRow(row)}>
        <View style={styles.cellContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.cellTitle}>{title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.cellSubtitle}>{subtitle}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <ListView
          style={styles.container}
          dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderRow}
        />
      )
  }       
}
```

#### JobDetailComponent.js

```
export default class JobDetailComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{this.props.test}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

So, as you can see, I am using a `TabBarIOS`. It has two tabs where one one of them is used to display the `ListView` with the job items. This tab has a `NavigatorIOS` as its root, which again has the `JobRootComponent` set as its `initialRoute`.

Everything works well with displaying the data. Only when I tap on a list item, instead of navigating to my `JobDetailComponent` (as is defined in `_pressRow()`), the app crashes giving the following error:

> **ExceptionsManager.js:76 Warning:**
>
> `React.createElement`: type should not
>   be `null`, `undefined`, `boolean`, or `number`. It should be a `string` (for DOM
>   elements) or a `ReactClass` (for composite components). Check the `render`
>   method of `NavigatorIOS`.

Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue myself, it was due to my import statements which I stupidly omitted in the code samples above because I thought that this was probably not where my issues were...

Anyways, the problem was that I imported the `JobDetailComponent` like this:

```
import { JobDetailComponent } from './JobDetailComponent'
```

instead of

```
import JobDetailComponent from './JobDetailComponent'
```